# Does the Metamask password need to be kept very secure?

Tags: metamask, password

My Metamask password is not as secure as it could be, as the same password has been used elsewhere.

Am I right in thinking that the password is only used locally in the Chrome plugin, and more than that is needed (seed words or private key) to access my account?

What is the best way for me to change the password?

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask pasword protects your private key, and that's why you should keep safe. Yes it is used locally in your browser.

Change password (simple Google search so someone could down-vote you for that)
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2168